# How to make my code support multiple data sources?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, aws-lambda

I'm looking to update some NodeJS code used on AWS Lambda so it can potentially use data from different sources.

As it stands, the code only supports using data from one source. I'd like the code to still work if we changed to a different source of data in the future.

What design pattern would this fall under? And are theire some good examples of how to implement something like this?

As an example, something like FlySystem https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem where it can handle file uploading to FTP or to Google Drive, just by changing the file adapter type.

Comment: You just named it yourself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: Do you know any good resources explaining how to implement the adapter pattern, specifically in Javascript?

Comment: It's a pattern. You can implement only your concrete `FileDataSource` interface. I suggest you study https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v2/docs/architecture/ and just try to implement their API in JS if that's what you want.

Comment: FlySystem was just an example, as its the fist thing that came to mind when thinking about what I want to implement. I used to be a PHP dev, but have moved over to NodeJS.

Comment: Still, if that's what you want to implement, just implement it!

Comment: It's more of a case that I don't know how to implement this pattern in JS, hence me asking for additional resources :)

Comment: Just use exactly the same data structures, classes, methods. Where exactly are you stuck? We certainly won't write all the code for you.